# How to convert SVG to PDF size equal to US letter / A4 size with 100% scale using CairoSVG python library?

Tags: python, pdf, svg, cairo, pycairo

I am converting SVG to pdf using python `CairoSVG` library, but I am unable to create exact A4(210mm x 297mm) or Letter size(216 × 279) PDF. I tried setting output height and width as:

```
 cairosvg.svg2pdf(url=self.svg_path,
                  write_to=self.output_file,
                  output_height=height #height of a4  or letter
                  output_width=width   #width of a4 or letter
                )
```

But in output PDF I am not getting size of A4 or letter as defined, and while printing PDF it require scale PDF, so any solution to overcome this issue and scale the pdf to 100% for either a4 or letter so no need to manual scaling while printing?

Comment: Which size do you get instead? What are the values of `width` and `height`?

Comment: `make_a4_pdf(a4_width=1056-0.09*1056, a4_heigth=816-0.09*816)` , this will call above specified method. 
This is input i provided, output pdf size of A4 I got, 720 × 556

Comment: Have you tried passing different numbers?

Comment: Yes I tried, but not get exact set in input.